# Time complexity of Prim's MST algorithm problem

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, time-complexity, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a graph problem where we have:

1. There are exactly *n* vertices and  *n-1* edges.
2. All vertices are connected with each other – i.e. the network consists of
   just one connected component. The network is thus a tree.
3. All edges have positive length (strictly greater than 0). All edges can carry
   traffic in both directions.
4. I am given the shortest path distance between each pair of vertices.

More formally: Let the actual vertice network be a tree *T*. Given just the
shortest path distances of *T*, you have to reconstruct the original network *T*.

**Input**: An *n × n* distance matrix *H* with *H<sub>i,j</sub> = δ<sub>T</sub> (i,j)*, where T is the actual
network of vertices and δ<sub>T</sub> is the shortest path distance between
vertice *i* and *j* in *T*.

**Output**: The *n −1* edges of *T*.

**Example:**

•T is the actual vertice network.

•H is the *n × n* shortest path distance matrix.

•G(H) is the complete graph on *n* nodes, where edge (i,j) has weight H<sub>i,j</sub>
– i.e. the shortest path distance in T.

**My question about Time Complexity:**

What is the running time of the algorithm resulting from running the Prim algorithm on the input and returning the list of edges as a function
of n? (Note that |E(G(H))|= Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)). Should Amortized analysis be used here? Im not really sure.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which implementation of Prim's algorithm you're using? For a complete graph, there's no special calculation that makes your inputs to the problem different from other graphs, except we know |E| is Θ(n^2). The [usual runtime bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm#Time_complexity) apply, depending on which data structure you're using.

Comment: @kcsquared its just the normal Prim's algorithm, so i think i just need to find the complexity for the general case which the other guy Pietro said in his answer, although i find his answer a bit confusing.

Comment: @kcsquared i added my answer i formulated in my post , can you check if its correct?

Comment: Thanks for adding more info, that is helpful. The answer says that H (the adj. matrix) has `n` members, is that a typo? Also, the implementation of Prim's with an adj. matrix that I'm aware of ([for example, this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prims-minimum-spanning-tree-mst-greedy-algo-5/)) doesn't modify that adj. matrix at all. You just need a separate 1D list of length `n` that tracks current minimum distances (and a set for vertices already in the MST). That algorithm does run in Theta(n^2) time.

Comment: @kcsquared hmm yeah i realized i made a mistake. This should be the input for my particular problem, could you help me formula it correctly? The input should be the one I specified in bold text in the post near the top. e.g "An n x n matrix H with ....."

Comment: @kcsquared cause it seems in my specific problem with the input being that as it is(see it above in the original question), its different than the general case? Because our "shortest path distance " are part of our adjacency matrix

Comment: You can still use the same formulation and algorithm: The complete graph will have a unique MST, which is the original tree. The fact that the input came from a distance matrix, which you're treating like an adjacency matrix, doesn't seem to affect Prim's algorithm compared to using an adjacency matrix normally.

Comment: @kcsquared Is my formulation then correct in that case or did i do anything wrong ? I should maybe just call it the shortest path matrix instead of adjacency matrix? I guess it has n x n members then, would that change run time?

Comment: Your initial description of the problem, and treating the distance matrix as the adjacency matrix of a complete graph seems fine and perfectly logical. The MST of that complete graph is the tree you want, and will be correctly returned by Prim's. The part that's unclear is just from the image of text you posted. The 'distance array' in Prim's sometimes called 'costs' or 'keys', is distinct from your distance/adjacency matrix. It's a 1D list of the current cheapest connection of each vertex to the MST. I'll post an answer with more details, and pseudocode for the whole algorithm.

Comment: @kcsquared if you're referring to the answer i added then dont mind it, i guess i was wrong, but to clear things up: Traditionally Prim's algorithm has an adjacency matrix and distance array that adds up to a runtime of O(n^2) HOWEVER, in my case the "adjacency" matrix is a shortest path distance matrix. Im not sure if this changes the runtime and how i would describe it in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of Prim's algorithm using the adjacency matrix of a complete graph is `Theta(n^2)`. We can see this from the pseudocode of Prim's algorithm with our adjacency matrix `H`:

1. Initialize a set `Q` of vertices not in the tree, initially all vertices. Choose the first vertex to be our root `R`.
2. Initialize two arrays of length `n`, `key` and `parent`. `key` will store, at position `i`, the minimum weight edge connecting the `i`th vertex to the current MST; initially, this is +infinity. `parent` will store, after the algorithm is done, the parent of each vertex in the MST rooted at `R`. Initially, `parent[i] = R` for all `i`, except the root, which has no parent.
3. Loop over the first row of `H` (corresponding to the root `R`) and assign `key[i] = H[0][i]`. Remove `R` from our set `Q`.
4. While `Q` is not empty:

   - Loop over `Q`, and extract any vertex `u` with minimum `key[u]`
   - For each vertex `v` from 0 to n-1:

     - If `v` in `Q` and `H[u][v] < key[v]`:

       - Set `key[v]` = `H[u][v]`
       - Set `parent[v]` = `u`

Here, the loop in (4) runs `n-1` times, and inside the loop, we do `Theta(n)` work. In total, that gives a runtime of `Theta(n^2)`, which is optimal for any algorithm that needs to read the entire adjacency matrix. In particular, for a generic complete graph, this is optimal, but this doesn't imply that Prim's algorithm is optimal for your specific case with a narrower class of graphs formed from distance matrices.

---

To show that your problem transformation is correct, we need to verify that, given a tree `T` with positive weights, the complete graph `G(H)` formed by taking the distance matrix of `T` as an adjacency matrix will satisfy:

1. `G(H)` has a unique minimum spanning tree
2. `T` is a minimum spanning tree of `G(H)`.

This requires proving several properties of minimum spanning trees in general. One theorem about minimum spanning trees, proven as Corollary 3.5 in [these MIT lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-design-and-analysis-of-algorithms-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT6_046JS12_lec03.pdf), says that:

> Let `G = (V,E,w)` be a connected, weighted, undirected graph. Let `T` be any MST and let `(U, V \ U)` be any cut. Then `T` contains a light edge for the cut.

Here, a 'light edge for a cut (U, V \ U)' means an edge whose weight is the minimum weight of all edges with exactly one endpoint in `U`.

Now, we just need to choose appropriate cuts to prove what we want. For an arbitrary edge `e` in your original tree `T`, consider the two trees `T1` and `T2` we get by deleting `e`.

Take the vertices of `T1`, which we'll call `V(T1)`, as our cut. We need to show that in the complete graph `G(H)`, the edge `e` is the unique light edge for that cut. In our original tree `T`, `e` is the only edge that crosses the cut. This means that any path with one endpoint `u` in `V(T1)` and the other endpoint `v` in `V(T2)` must include `e`.

Since all the weights are positive, this means that the distance in T, `distance(u,v) > weight(e)`, for any `u, v such that (u in V(T1), v in V(T2), and (u, v) != e)`. Since the distance in `T` between `u` and `v` is the weight of the edge `(u, v)` in our complete graph `G(H)`, this means that `e` is the unique minimum weight edge that crosses the cut. Since `e` was an arbitrary edge in `T`, this now means that all edges of `T` must be in our MST for `G(H)`, so the unique MST of `G(H)` is `T`.